# Using wget with shell_exec and at command?

Tags: php, linux, wget, shell-exec, at-job

I've been struggling with shell_exec PHP function and at linux command for 2 days.
To make it short, this works:

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/at 09:32 <<EOF
       touch /var/www/website/hello.txt 
EOF'
);
```

this doesn't:

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/at 09:32 <<EOF
       wget -O - -q -t 1 "http://192.168.56.101/website/test.php?param=hello" >/dev/null 2>&1
EOF'

);
```

Why ?

(note: the code above does work in console)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of wget.  And cron instead of `at`.  `shell_exec` should be considered harmful and a last resort in the general case.

Comment: Does the job end up in `at`? (http://serverfault.com/questions/174678/how-do-i-print-contents-of-at-jobs)

Comment: What's the return value of the `system_exec` call?

Comment: Thanks, but how should I use file_get_contents in shell_exec ?
Yes the job end up in at.

Comment: @Duddy67, what are you intending to do with that wget command, because right now you're fetching the URL, printing it to `stdout` (using `-O -`) and then throwing it away (using the redirect to /dev/null), it's essentially a no-op, so I don't even know what you want to do with this file.  Do you want to save it to a disk?  Echo it?  Mutate it?

Comment: I just want to load the test.php page (in order to run a script) with a GET parameter.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter to what?

Comment: To the PHP script within test.php.

Comment: `file_get_contents("http://192.168.56.101/website/test.php?param=hello");`  There's a link to the documentation in my very first comment.

Comment: I meant how to put this in the shell_exec.
Something like that ?:

shell_exec('/usr/bin/at 09:32 <<EOF
       file_get_contents("http://192.168.56.101/website/test.php?param=hello") 
EOF'
             );

BTW the following works perfectly too: 
shell_exec('/usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 "http://192.168.56.101/website/test.php?param=hello" >/dev/null 2>&1');

Comment: You don't need to use shell_exec.  If you want to run a thing at a certain time, you can either use "at" directly, to call the php script, if you want to trigger it manually, or you can use cron if you want to trigger it on a schedule (every day or every week).  I'm seriously confused as to why you're wrapping this in a php script in the first place.

Comment: Further, if you're using php, the correct way to fetch a file from a URL is `file_get_contents` which is a php builtin.  You just simply invoke `<?php file_get_contents('http://example.com/') ?>`.  No shell_exec, no wget, no dependencies on external binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've got it at last !!

For those who are interested the pb comes that the wget command also need to be invoked with the full path (ie: /usr/bin/wget).
What misleaded me is that the touch command doesn't need it. It's weird but anyway here's the working code:

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/at 09:32 <<EOF
       /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 "http://192.168.56.101/website/test.php?param=hello" >/dev/null 2>&1
EOF'
);
```

Comment: This is because touch is a shell builtin.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity No it isn't.